# How do I update the main activity after getting data from the user from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The user selects an item from the navigation drawer and it takes them to an activity with the following code:

```
public void addOk(View v){
    String sendName = name.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", sendName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Which method would I use to update the main activity the user just came from?
`onResume()` doesn't work because everytime I start the application `onResume()` will be run.

My main activity has the following code but I don't know how to implement it so it only runs when the `addOk` button is pressed

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    if(Title == null || Title.trim().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The text field is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        addArray.add(Title);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
        show.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: That code already does run when addOk is pressed.. The Activity is started, and that code runs.

Comment: you need to use startActivityForResult method. You can find a lot of info about it. It is simple for use

Comment: Have you considered using an interface and just do some callbacks? Or if you're just worried that the code in onResume() should not run on the first time it is created, why not just have boolean variable as a checker wherein it turns to false for the first time it goes through onResume()

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to implement it so it only runs when the addOk button is pressed

You can implement a button click in the onCreate method of your activity like below

```
 Button okAddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok_add);
    okAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
            if(Title == null || Title.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The text field is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                addArray.add(Title);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
                show.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });
```